# how to use vi18n in different js that run within the same page

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-mix

I'm doing a template which has 3 sections.

- Header
- Aside
- content_section

[image]

Each section is a different spa and the only thing that changes is **content_section**

how can I separate aside and header in a script different from the content_section script so that every time there is a change in the first two is reflected in all the sections

currently this is my script:

```
require('../bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n';
import spanish from '../Assets/Lang/Sections/AdminSection/es';
import eng from '../Assets/Lang/Sections/AdminSection/en';

var messages = {
    es: spanish,
    en: eng
}
const i18n = new VueI18n({
    locale: 'es', // set locale
    fallbackLocale: 'es',
    messages // set locale messages
});

const vue_template = new Vue({
    i18n,
    el: '#vue-template',
    components: {
        'aside-component': require('./Template/Components/AsideComponent.vue'),
        'header-component': require('./Template/Components/HeraderComponent.vue'),



   },
}


const componentes_vue = new Vue({
    i18n,
    el: '#vue-component',
    components:{
        'vue-section-component': require('./section_1.vue'),
    }
}
```

I am compiling all this with laravel mix, I would like to separate the two instances so that on the one hand the instance of vue_template is always compiled and the instance components_vue is compiled only when necessary

Comment: try to use vue-router https://router.vuejs.org/